# Tonelli’s theorem, assuming $\mu$ and $\nu$ are s-finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1, \mu)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2, \nu)$ be measurable spaces, such that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are [s-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-finite_measure) measures, i.e they can be written as countable union of finite measures.

Suppose $f : \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \to [0,\infty]$ is a $\mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2$-measurable function. Prove that conclusions of Tonelli’s theorem still holds under these assumptions.

[image]

Since s-finitness doesn't imply $\sigma$-finitness and the proof of the Theorem depends on this property, I'm not sure how to prove this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu =\sum \mu_n$ and $\nu =\sum \nu_n$ then $\int f d(\mu \times \nu)=\sum_n \sum_m \int f d(\mu_n \times \mu_m)$ so $\int f d(\mu \times \nu)=\int\int f d\mu d \nu$. You can always switch infinite sums and integrals when the integrand is non-negative. [This is another application of Tonelli's Theorem since infinite sums are integrals w.r.t counting measure and  counting measure on the integers is sigma finite].