# $s$-finite vs. $\sigma$-finite measures

Tags: measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Many results in measure theory are first proven for finite measures and then extended to $\sigma$-finite ones. Here are some examples:

- [**$\pi\text{-}\lambda$ theorem approach to proving two measures are the same.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Example)
- [**Fubini-Tonelli.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions)
- [**Lebesgue decomposition.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem)
- [**Radon-Nikodym theorem.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)

Other results (e.g. [**Duality $(L^1(\mu))^*\simeq L^\infty(\mu)$.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces) for $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$) are stated directly in terms of $\sigma$-finite measures.

In the theory of random measures $s$-finite measures seem to be preferred over $\sigma$-finite ones, providing a more flexible theoretical framework presumably. Recall that a measure $\mu$ is $s$-finite if there are finite measures $\mu_n$, $n\in\Bbb{N}$, with $\mu=\sum_0^\infty\mu_n$.

> **Question 1.** Which results valid for $\sigma$-finite measures remain true for $s$-finite measures?

It seems pretty clear that the **Fubini-Tonelli Theorem** remains valid for $s$-finite measures since if $\mu=\sum_0^\infty\mu_n$ and $\nu=\sum_0^\infty\nu_n$ one ought to have $\mu\otimes\nu=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\mu_m\otimes\nu_n$, and this question was already raised [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253638/tonelli-s-theorem-assuming-mu-and-nu-are-s-finite). Using the $\pi\text{-}\lambda$ theorem approach to proving two measures are the same ought to be transposable to $s$-finite measures if one can do it ``one $\mu_n/\nu_n$ at a time''. I don't believe that the **Radon-Nikodym Theorem** remains true, for instance if we take $\mu$ the counting measure on $\Bbb{N}$ and $\nu$ the measure $$\nu(A)=\begin{cases}A=\emptyset:&0\\A\neq\emptyset:&+\infty\end{cases}$$ We have $\mu\ll\nu$ but there can't be a function $f$ with $\mu=f\cdot \nu$. What about **Lebesgue decomposition**?

> **Quesstion 2.** When should one work with $\sigma$-finite measures / when with $s$-finite measures?

To explain a little more in detail: it seems to me that $\sigma$-finite measures are interesting when one is interested in actually using a measure to do integration. To wit, I never heard of $s$-finite measures before reading up on point processes. On the other hand, $s$-finite measures seem to be the right concept when one is interested in measure valued processes, i.e. random measures, but doesn't really care to apply results from measure theory to and perform actual integration using these measures. Is that impression correct?